# UIRefreshControl result in incorrect TableView offset

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uirefreshcontrol

While `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from a TableViewContorller (e.g. `aTVC`) to another (e.g. `bTVC`), if I hit the back button on `bTVC` while it's `UIRefreshControl` is displaying, will result in incorrect offset of the `TableView` in `aTVC`:

[image: bTVC]

The black section is due to the different height of the NavigationBar when `UIRefreshControl` of `bTVC` is displaying while hitting the back button:

[image: aTVC]

I tried to cancel the refreshControl before switching from `bTVC`, but without success.

Any idea?

Comment: Try to stop refresh control animation on `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillDisappear`?

Comment: tried both with `-endRefreshing`. Still the same.

Comment: show the code where did you initiate the `UIRefreshControl`, and how did you add it into the `UITableView` and how did you tried to `endRefreshing`.

Comment: I have removed the feature completely months ago as I have read it on the radar that there’s no correct solution to this matter as long as you do this w/o blocking other user interactions. The problem is while you are endRefreshing and the user decided to navigate between VCs w/o RC, it will break. Since blocking UI interaction is against Apple’s guidelines, it’s better not using it at all in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `UIRefreshControl` in `ViewDidLoad`(or at the place you want) and removing (`refreshControl.removeFromSuperview()`) in `viewWillDisappear` instead of `endRefreshing`.

Comment: Removing it from super view isn’t the same as end refreshing, as the previous will simply make it gone w/o proper animation and might break things within the RC code structure (threading etc.). It’s not about when you do it, because the VC navigation system does the transition asynchronously as your RC animation, rendered the VC’s content view with incorrect top position.